# Does the Golden Ratio Apply to Timing as Well?

Tags: mathematical-philosophy, soft-question

I've seen the golden section applied to art, but does it apply to sound/timing as well?  Just curious.

Comment: -1. This question may be inappropriate for mathoverflow. It's certainly mis-tagged. 

Comment: Mario Livio's book on the golden ratio (http://www.amazon.com/Golden-Ratio-Worlds-Astonishing-Number/dp/0767908163) does a pretty good job of debunking most golden ratio myths.  You should probably read that before asking such questions.

Comment: And that book is "debunked" in the Notices article which Scott Morrison mentions in his answer.

Comment: I dont think reading a basic book/paper in a subject is a requirement to asking a question about it.

Comment: I agree with Scott Morrison.

Comment: I don't think MO is a good place for this question. Its connection to mathematics is at best extremely tenuous. It may be more appropriate at some of the math forums listed in the FAQ.

Comment: The golden ratio is the "most irrational number" in a certain sense. Presumably if you played two frequencies at a ratio of \phi : 1 it would be particularly discordant, although I haven't actually tried this.

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly not, seeing as the golden ratio has almost nothing to do with (classical) art and architecture anyway. See for example [this review](http://www.ams.org/notices/200503/rev-markowsky.pdf) in the Notices.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a page on its relation to music: http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibInArt.html#music

Answer (score 2):

My guess this is not an appropriate question for MO, but being weekend and all...

I have heard of one approach to memorization which consists in repeating something in time intervals corresponding to the Fibonacci sequence.  I did not find a reference, so take this with a grain of salt, though :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe so Debussy and apparently others used the Fibonacci sequence in his work.
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) for more information and references. Especially see the following:
Roy Howat (1983). Debussy in Proportion: A Musical Analysis. Cambridge University Press. ISBN 0-521-31145-4. There is a preview of this book on Google books.